In the TurtleBot3 Gazebo simulation, the angular velocity exhibits significant fluctuations at certain points, leading to instability
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and Gazebo 11.14 to simulate the TurtleBot 3 Waffle Pi robot. I run the code below, and record the command data and odmetry data form topic "/odom".
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>
#include "nav_msgs/Path.h"
#include "nav_msgs/Odometry.h"
#include <tf2_ros/buffer.h>
#include <tf2/LinearMath/Matrix3x3.h>
#include "tf2_ros/transform_listener.h"
#include "tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h"
#include "narrow_space_navigation/point_style.h"
#include "narrow_space_navigation/utils.h"
#include <random>

Controller::car_state cur_pose;

void odom_callback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr &msg)
{
    try
    {
        geometry_msgs::Quaternion odom_quat = msg->pose.pose.orientation;
        tf2::Quaternion quat;
        tf2::fromMsg(odom_quat, quat);

        double roll, pitch, yaw;
        tf2::Matrix3x3(quat).getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);

        cur_pose.x = msg->pose.pose.position.x;
        cur_pose.y = msg->pose.pose.position.y;
        cur_pose.yaw = yaw;
        cur_pose.v = msg->twist.twist.linear.x;
        cur_pose.w = msg->twist.twist.angular.z;

    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        ROS_INFO("Some errors in the odom_callback.");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ros::init(argc,argv,"ramdom_test");
    FILE* new_log;
    new_log = fopen("new_test.txt", "w");
    ROS_INFO("ros init");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Publisher twist_pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/cmd_vel", 10);
    ros::Subscriber odom_sub = nh.subscribe("/odom", 10, odom_callback);

    int multiplier = atoi(argv[1]);
    geometry_msgs::Twist control_output;
    double dt = 0.02;
    double a = 0.0;
    ros::Rate r(50);
    while (ros::ok())
    {
        a = a + dt;
        control_output.linear.x = 0.25 * (1 - cos(a)) * multiplier;
        double w_acc = 0.25 * sin(a) * multiplier;
        control_output.angular.z = control_output.angular.z + w_acc * dt;
        r.sleep();
        ros::spinOnce();
        twist_pub.publish(control_output);
        fprintf(new_log, "%.6f "
                             "%.6f %.6f %.6f %.6f %.6f %.6f %.6f\n",
                cur_pose.x, cur_pose.y, cur_pose.yaw, control_output.linear.x, control_output.angular.z,
                cur_pose.v, cur_pose.w, w_acc);
        fflush(new_log);
    }
    return 0;
}

With the default gazebo urdf of the waffle pi robot, and multiplier = 4 ( which means the linear control speed cmd_v = 0.25 * multiplier  * (1 - cos(a)), angular speed cmd_w = cmd_w  + 0.25 * multiplier * sin(a), a += dt, please see the code above).
We have: (w_is is the angular speed from "/odom" and the w_cmd is the command, please neglect the w_should)

It is clear this urdf settings can not handle that much angular speed and angular acceleration. So I change the urdf into this:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="turtlebot3_waffle_pi_sim" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
  <xacro:arg name="laser_visual"  default="false"/>
  <xacro:arg name="camera_visual" default="false"/>
  <xacro:arg name="imu_visual"    default="false"/>

  <gazebo reference="base_link">
    <material>Gazebo/DarkGrey</material>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="wheel_left_link">
    <mu1>1.0</mu1>
    <mu2>1.0</mu2>
    <soft_cfm>0.0</soft_cfm>
    <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
    <kp>1e15</kp>
    <kd>4e12</kd>
    <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
    <maxVel>10</maxVel>
    <fdir1>1 0 0</fdir1>
    <material>Gazebo/FlatBlack</material>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="wheel_right_link">
    <mu1>1.0</mu1>
    <mu2>1.0</mu2>
    <soft_cfm>0.0</soft_cfm>
    <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
    <kp>1e15</kp>
    <kd>4e12</kd>
    <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
    <maxVel>10</maxVel>
    <fdir1>1 0 0</fdir1>
    <material>Gazebo/FlatBlack</material>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="caster_back_right_link">
    <mu1>0.01</mu1>
    <mu2>0.01</mu2>
    <soft_cfm>0.0</soft_cfm>
    <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
    <kp>1e15</kp>
    <kd>4e12</kd>
    <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
    <maxVel>10</maxVel>
    <material>Gazebo/FlatBlack</material>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="caster_back_left_link">
    <mu1>0.01</mu1>
    <mu2>0.01</mu2>
    <soft_cfm>0.0</soft_cfm>
    <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
    <kp>1e15</kp>
    <kd>4e12</kd>
    <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
    <maxVel>10</maxVel>
    <material>Gazebo/FlatBlack</material>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="imu_link">
    <sensor type="imu" name="imu">
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <visualize>$(arg imu_visual)</visualize>
    </sensor>
    <material>Gazebo/Grey</material>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="turtlebot3_waffle_pi_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
      <commandTopic>cmd_vel</commandTopic>
      <odometryTopic>odom</odometryTopic>
      <odometryFrame>odom</odometryFrame>
      <odometrySource>world</odometrySource>
      <publishOdomTF>true</publishOdomTF>
      <robotBaseFrame>base_footprint</robotBaseFrame>
      <publishWheelTF>false</publishWheelTF>
      <publishTf>true</publishTf>
      <publishWheelJointState>true</publishWheelJointState>
      <legacyMode>false</legacyMode>
      <updateRate>100</updateRate>
      <leftJoint>wheel_left_joint</leftJoint>
      <rightJoint>wheel_right_joint</rightJoint>
      <wheelSeparation>0.287</wheelSeparation>
      <wheelDiameter>0.066</wheelDiameter>
      <wheelAcceleration>4</wheelAcceleration>
      <wheelTorque>10</wheelTorque>
      <rosDebugLevel>na</rosDebugLevel>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="imu_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_imu.so">
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <bodyName>imu_link</bodyName>
      <frameName>imu_link</frameName>
      <topicName>imu</topicName>
      <serviceName>imu_service</serviceName>
      <gaussianNoise>0.0</gaussianNoise>
      <updateRate>0</updateRate>
      <imu>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <rate>
            <mean>0.0</mean>
            <stddev>2e-4</stddev>
            <bias_mean>0.0000075</bias_mean>
            <bias_stddev>0.0000008</bias_stddev>
          </rate>
          <accel>
            <mean>0.0</mean>
            <stddev>1.7e-2</stddev>
            <bias_mean>0.1</bias_mean>
            <bias_stddev>0.001</bias_stddev>
          </accel>
        </noise>
      </imu>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="base_scan">
    <material>Gazebo/FlatBlack</material>
    <sensor type="ray" name="lds_lfcd_sensor">
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <visualize>$(arg laser_visual)</visualize>
      <update_rate>5</update_rate>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>360</samples>
            <resolution>1</resolution>
            <min_angle>0.0</min_angle>
            <max_angle>6.28319</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.120</min>
          <max>3.5</max>
          <resolution>0.015</resolution>
        </range>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.01</stddev>
        </noise>
      </ray>
      <plugin name="gazebo_ros_lds_lfcd_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so">
        <topicName>scan</topicName>
        <frameName>base_scan</frameName>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>

<!--link : https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/camera/-->
  <gazebo reference="camera_rgb_frame">
    <sensor type="camera" name="Pi Camera">
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <visualize>$(arg camera_visual)</visualize>
      <camera>
          <horizontal_fov>1.085595</horizontal_fov>
          <image>
              <width>640</width>
              <height>480</height>
              <format>R8G8B8</format>
          </image>
          <clip>
              <near>0.03</near>
              <far>100</far>
          </clip>
      </camera>
      <plugin name="camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
        <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
        <updateRate>30.0</updateRate>
        <cameraName>camera</cameraName>
        <frameName>camera_rgb_optical_frame</frameName>
        <imageTopicName>rgb/image_raw</imageTopicName>
        <cameraInfoTopicName>rgb/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
        <hackBaseline>0.07</hackBaseline>
        <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
        <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
        <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
        <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
        <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>

</robot>

Now the control graph is:

It looks good but there is a significant fluctuation at the begining, and if I run another code, which is a model predict controller to follow a path. The graph is:

we still get some significant fluctuations, in this picture, at the end of the control, which will make the final precision not that good.
I wonder where this fluctuation comes from?
I observe that the robot does perform this fluctuating angular velocity, so maybe it's not just the odom, right? And these fluctuations seem to be in the direction to the X-axis, are they interspersed with some unknown 0 angular velocity control signals outside my control?
Is this potentially related to my control algorithm? (The command is smooth enough, so I doubt it's the cause.)
Could it be due to the modifications made in the Gazebo URDF file or specific settings in Gazebo?
I'm uncertain, so I would appreciate any insights you might have if you're familiar with the Gazebo simulation platform. Thank you for your help!

You might get better answers on https://robotics.stackexchange.com.

@ChristianFritz Thank you for your reply, I will also ask there, I asked once before, but no one replied to me. lol.
